# Android studio unable to build downloaded project

Tags: android, build, navigation-drawer, sample

I'm very new to Android, I downloaded sample project from Developer.android.com,
and when I open in Android studio,I couldn't see clean or Build option.[image]

1. please guide how to build this project.
2. Is there any good sample code for Navigation Drawer with activities and Images?
   Thanks.

Comment: Android studio builds on gradle system, seems no gradle file in project. Its eclipse project i think.

Comment: You can see this [Navigation drawer example](http://javatechig.com/android/navigation-drawer-android-example) and [Sample Git hub code](https://github.com/npanigrahy/Android-Lollipop-Navigation-Drawer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Kristy Welsh pointed you need to import the project.

[Video how to import](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oB73LES8aac).

Project with [Navigation Drawer](https://github.com/mgolokhov/dodroid).

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you have a project that was created in eclipse.  Try importing that project into Android Studio and it will do the build for you.

Answer (score 0):

There should be a big green play-symbol you can click. It then opens a pop-up where you can choose to either run it on an emulated version or load it onto a connected android device (provided you have the drivers and the phone allows this direct installation). An alternative would be to build an .apk and put it into your phone's file system to then install it via the phone. This takes way more time but is the way to distribute your app to friends without using the play store.

Answer (score 0):

if there is no error after downloading ,try to sync the project

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a Configuration at Run>Run Configuration>Green Plus>Android Applicatio. now select your Launch Activity and your Module